# jQuery code is too verbose, would like pointers on how to make it shorter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code that I would like reviews and pointers on on how to bring its line count down and shorten.

```
$('#p1').click(function() {
    $('#list').fadeOut(450);
    $('#q1').delay(600).fadeIn(450)
});
$('#p2').click(function() {
    $('#list').fadeOut(450);
    $('#q2').delay(600).fadeIn(450)
});
$('#p3').click(function() {
    $('#list').fadeOut(450);
    $('#q3').delay(600).fadeIn(450)
});
$('#p4').click(function() {
    $('#list').fadeOut(450);
    $('#q4').delay(600).fadeIn(450)
});

...

$('#p12').click(function() {
    $('#list').fadeOut(450);
    $('#q12').delay(600).fadeIn(450)
});
$('#p13').click(function() {
    $('#list').fadeOut(450);
    $('#q13').delay(600).fadeIn(450)
});
```

Can this code be better optimised? Or at least made less verbose?

Comment: Oh man, this is a real massacre with false answers because of scope issues in a loop. Does anyone have a good link to one of the many questions here about that issue?

Comment: @Thilo, you should search "javascript onclick loop" and you get millions of questions about it :)

Comment: So this is a Code Review, yes?

Comment: um, how about just giving all those items a class instead/in addition? `$('.p').click(...`

Comment: Next time you want to have your code reviewed, please post on [CodeReview.SE].

Comment: @AnnaLear: No, please don't. This is a perfectly good question for Stack Overflow. A very specific problem was pointed out in the code (too repetitive) and the OP asked how to fix that. And looking at all the discussion about it, it was very informative for everyone here, started a discussion about using ids versus classes, about using event delegation, and about variable scope in JS.

Comment: @Thilo I'm not saying this is a bad question in any way. But, we do have an SE site specifically for this kind of thing, so it's at least partially my job to make that known.

Comment: If this question went to CodeReview instead of SO, it would have been a loss for SO (and maybe also for the OP, because there are much more eyes on SO).

Comment: The OP wanted a code review. Simple as that. Refactoring and reducing lines is part of what Code Review is about. This is a chunk of code that wanted to be smaller. Saying no one goes to Code Review because we're all here is self-defeating and narrow-minded. @thi

Comment: @Thilo - here's a [comprehensive list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript+loops+closures) of questions about creating closures inside loops.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use a `for` loop, but you should make sure the loop counter's value gets into a correct scope for `click` event handler:

```
var clickHandler = function(k) {
    return function() {
        $('#list').fadeOut(450);
        $('#q' + k).delay(600).fadeIn(450);
    };
};
for (var i = 1; i < 14; ++i) {
    $('#p' + i).click(clickHandler(i));
}
```

Otherwise the `delay` and `fadeIn` would get applied to `#q13` element exclusively, since actual counter (with its final value of 13) would get into closure.

---

**EDIT**: Since quite a lot of answers got it wrong here, I'll attempt to explain more precisely what's going on in this code, as it seems to be pretty confusing.

The "natural" solution with injecting the click handler directly into loop would be the following:

```
for(var i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    $('#p'+i).click(function() {
        $('#list').fadeOut(450);
        $('#q'+i).delay(600).fadeIn(450)
    });
}
```

But this is not at all equivalent to the extended form, which lists all the 13 variants one after another. The problem is that while there are indeed 13 functions created here, they are all closed over the same variable `i`, whose value changes. It finally arrives at the value of `13` and the loop ends.

Some time later the functions attached to `#p1`...`#p13` elements are called (when one of those elements are clicked) and they use that final value of `i`. This results in only `#q13` being animated.

What needs to be done here is to do something called [lambda lifting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_lifting) and eliminate the free variable `i`, whose value gets inadvertly changed. A common technique for that is to provide a "factory function" which accepts value for our variable and outputs an actual function which we'll use as event handler:

```
var clickHandler = function(k) {
    return function() {
        $('#list').fadeOut(450);
        $('#q' + k).delay(600).fadeIn(450);
    };
};
```

Since the scope of `k` parameter is local to `clickHandler`, every call to `clickHandler` gets different `k` variable. The function returned from `clickHandler` is therefore closed over different variables, which can in turn have different values. This is exactly what we need. We can then call `clickHandler` from our loop, passing it the counter's value:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 14; ++i) {
    $('#p' + i).click(clickHandler(i));
}
```

I hope this makes the difference somewhat clearer.

---

**EDIT**: As Esailija pointed out in the comments, it is also possible to use `jQuery.each` to achieve similar effect:

```
$.each(new Array(13), function(idx) {
    $('#p' + (idx + 1)).click(function() {
        $('#list').fadeOut(450);
        $('#q' + idx).delay(600).fadeIn(450);
    });
});
```

This is probably the solution of choice if you're already aware of the closure/scoping issue I've tried to outline above.

Comment: +1 only answer that takes care of scope...

Comment: You could just use `jQuery.each` which takes care of it naturally

Comment: `jQuery.each` is all fine and dandy, but I think at some point every JavaScript programmer needs to understand what exactly is going on here. And while for this particular example it would do trick, in general it has its own catches (such as probably different referent of `this` inside and outside of `jQuery.each` "loop") that you should bear in mind while using it.

Comment: @Xion, just using the factory function hardly explains it either, it's just a RY way of doing the same thing. My comment was made before you edited your post to have an explanation. `this` is used in the onclick handler, which has nothing to do with the way you loop it - it will be the element either way once the onclick is called.

Comment: @Xion: The "natural" solution can be fixed in this way as well : `for(var i = 1; i < 14; i++) {
    var local = i;
    $('#p'+i).click(function() {
        $('#list').fadeOut(450);
        $('#q'+local).delay(600).fadeIn(450)
    });
}` . That is, declare a `local` variable inside the loop, and use that variable in the click handler, instead of loop variable.

Comment: Nope. Despite the appearance, `local` will have scope limited to the whole function that encloses the `for` loop. All click handlers will therefore be closed over this one variable, resulting in the same error as in "natural" solution.

Comment: @Xion: No. The local variable will be created each time it is initialized with `i`, and so the handler will get its own copy of `i`, which wouldn't change.

Comment: No, it will not. Putting `var local` inside the `for` loop doesn't change its scope. It's still local within the **function**, not the loop block. JavaScript doesn't have block scope at all.

Try the following simple example in your browser's console to see it for yourself:
`a = []; for (var i = 0; i < 2; ++i) { var local = i; a.push(function() { alert(local); }); }`
Invoking `a[0]()` and `a[1]()` will both result in alert with `1`, rather than `0` and `1`, respectively.

Comment: returning a function you're creating a different annonymous function for each element. but would be better using just one function to reduce memory usage. and let each element handle the #p part

Comment: When in doubt you can just [unroll the loop](http://jsfiddle.net/d37n4/1/) to make sure. It should be very clear from there on what the value `i` resolves to once any of those functions are called after the loop.

Comment: +1 for lambda lifting, seen the issue in my JS but haven't heard the name for this technique.

Comment: I've had to do this before - feels kludgy but it works. Still...I'd feel better about writing a single function with a `switch(true){...}` : P

Answer (score 14):

The ideal solution, IMO, contrary to the accepted answer, is not to base your code around relationships between `id` values, but to base it around relationships in the DOM. jQuery provides you with an [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) method, that allows you to see where your element is in relation to its siblings.  You can then use this value to select the appropriate other element to show.

This does, of course, require you to structure your HTML in a semantic way.  For instance:

```
<div id="list">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
    <a href="#">Link 7</a>
    <a href="#">Link 8</a>
</div>
<div id="questions"> <!-- perhaps this is what q stands for... -->
    <div>1 ...</div>
    <div>2 ...</div>
    <div>3 ...</div>
    <div>4 ...</div>
    <div>5 ...</div>
    <div>6 ...</div>
    <div>7 ...</div>
    <div>8 ...</div>
</div>
```

The first link applies to the first nested `div`, the second to the second, etc. The markup is simple, easy to read and clearly semantic.

Your code can then be very simple, with no need to worry about factories. Indeed, the nicest way to do it is with event bubbling and delegation, handled admirably by jQuery's [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) method (in 1.7; before this, use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)).

```
$('#list').on('click', 'a', function() {
    $('#list').fadeOut(450);
    $('#questions div').eq($(this).index()).delay(600).fadeIn(450);
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eCSzR/) (I know the animation looks a little clunky, sorry.)

`$(this).index()` finds the relation of the current element in relation to its siblings. [`.eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq) filters the selection (of `#questions div` elements) to find the element in the corresponding position.

The code may not be *quite* as fast (if you use `id` values, it will almost certainly be mildly faster), but your markup is simpler and therefore more robust.

Comment: While I agree that DOM data is an ugly hack, it will scale much better with larger set of elements especially when we are talking mouseovers or events where performance is more critical. So far for acceptable performance in those situations the cleanest solution I have found is unique hashes so the index lookup stays fast but it's still pretty ugly. Still +1 though since we are talking small amount of elements and a simple click here :)

Answer (score 12):

If you must insist on not using event delegation and classes then:

```
$.each( new Array(13), function(index){
    $('#p'+(index+1) ).click(function() {
        $('#list').fadeOut(450);
        $('#q'+(index+1)).delay(600).fadeIn(450)
    });
});
```

Using classes and delegation:

```
$( document ).delegate( ".my-class", "click", function(){
var idIndex = this.id.match( /\d+$/, )[0];

        $('#list').fadeOut(450);
            $('#q'+idIndex).delay(600).fadeIn(450)

});
```

Comment: Before someone downvotes for using a class: there is efficiency benefit of using classname delegation instead of some overly complex trick selector  as it needs to be evaluated every time the document is clicked.

Comment: almost +1 for classes, but you are still using ids for matching the two corresponding `p` and `q`. Presumably that can also be done with classes and relative positions in the document.

Comment: @Thilo, it's probably more efficient to get the id directly instead of comparing document positions each time. And since the id's are there anyway, why not use them :) At least +1 for the new Array trick if anything :D

Comment: The id are probably not there anyway, but had to be added for just this animation (just my assumption, of course).

Comment: +1 for using classes and event delegation! For folks who don't want regex, they could do this if the prefer `$('#'+this.id.replace('p','q'))`.

Answer (score 6):

Like others, you can use a `for-loop` to do this, but you are actually bounding yourself to `14` `p`s and whenever you add a new `p` you need to increase your `for-loop` test condition.

This is what I would do:

```
$("[id^=p]").bind("click", function() {
    $('#list').fadeOut(450);
    $('#q' + $(this).attr("id").match(/^#p(\d+)$/i)[1]).delay(600).fadeIn(450)
})
```

Comment: +1 for avoiding the closure problem entirely, even though you are using regexes which some may consider a problem in itself ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Couldn't you just use a class instead of all these different ids? And then some navigation to find the matching other element?

```
$('.myCoolEffect').click(function(event) {
    $('#list').fadeOut(450);
    // find the matching element based on this on somehow
    $(event.currentTarget).up(1).delay(600).fadeIn(450);
});
```

Comment: Where did you get `.up` from?

Comment: `.up` is just an example. Presumably there is some kind of fixed way to navigate from `p5` to `q5` in the document.

Answer (score 4):

Try this,

```
$('[id^="p"]').live('click', function(e){
    var temp = this.id.match(/^p(\d+)$/);
    if(temp){
       $('#list').fadeOut(450);
       $('#q' + temp[1]).delay(600).fadeIn(450);
    }

});
```

I have used [jqueryStartsWith Selector](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20starts%20with%20selector&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/&ei=WsnQTrrnHsSHrAf4s425DA&usg=AFQjCNFLvKsFLaadTmLDnPiJ5xOHtQb-8g) & [live function](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jquery%20live&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http://api.jquery.com/live/&ei=s8nQTqviHcLtrQedw-S8DA&usg=AFQjCNHPnKvzKaTw54m1H-YHMmd8NEWjTQ).

**Update:**

As, [Xion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/434799/xion) commented, If you use this code, it will affect the all other elements of whose `id's` are starting with `p`.

If you could add more characters in the id means, this will not be a problem.

**Update 2:**

As, [BrunoLM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/340760/brunolm) mentioned in the comment, i have changed the code slightly to not to trigger the event for other elements on the dom that are having the id starts with `p`.

The `var temp = this.id.match(/^p(\d+)$/);` and the following if block takes care of other elements of whose `id` is starts with `p`.

`match(/^p(\d+)$/)` returns `null` for the id's like `pblabla, p2sdad, pdasds2323` and it returns an array for the id's like `p1, p2, ... p100000....`

Comment: Note that this way (as well as the one posted by Munim) assumes that there are no other elements whose `id` starts with 'p' - a tough call, I'd say. It would be more reasonable to introduce a class for `#pN` elements and select on it.

Comment: you could check the id against `/^p(\d+)$/` before continuing with the event.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('div').filter(function () {
  return this.id.match(/^p([0-9]+)$/);
}).click(function () {
  $('#list').fadeOut(450);
  $('#' +$(this).attr('id').replace('p','q')).delay(600).fadeIn(450)
});
```